# Dalvik Verifier Error: tried to get class from non-ref register v14

Tags: android, dalvik, smali

I am playing around with writting smali and get the following error:

```
W/dalvikvm( 2798): VFY: tried to get class from non-ref register v14 (type=0)
W/dalvikvm( 2798): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x6e at 0x001c
W/dalvikvm( 2798): VFY:  rejected Lcom/test/Smali1;.doTest(Lc
om/test/Smali2;Z)Ljava/lang/String;
W/dalvikvm( 2798): Verifier rejected class Lcom/test/Smali;
```

My smali code:

```
.method  doTest(Lcom/test/Smali2;Z)Ljava/lang/String;
.registers 22
.prologue
move/16 v16, p2
move-object/from16 v15, p1
move-object/from16 v14, p0
check-cast v15, Lcom/test/Smali2;
check-cast v14, Lcom/test/Smali1;
invoke-virtual {v14}, Lcom/test/Smali1;->test()
```

I tried to find the problem by looking at the CodeVerifier code, but I am not sure why v14 is detected as non-ref register.

Comment: It's failing on opcode 0x6e, `invoke-virtual`.  `type=0` indicates that the type of the register is unknown.  Are you showing the entire method, or is there a way to branch back to that invoke-virtual instruction from farther on in the method?

Comment: You can run baksmali with the -r option on your compiled dex file, which will show you detailed info on how the register types propogate.